# Автовысота результата группы данных в DevExpress Reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

Делаю табличный отчет с помощью DevExpress Reports. Имеется группировка данных по полю и футером группы с суммой по полям группы. В бенде Detail перечисляются все записи группы и в зависимости от данных высота строк таблицы подстраивается под содержимое. В футер выводится сумма, установлены те же параметры полей, что и в Detail, что могут расти (Can grow) и выбран параметр Summary = Group. По выводу данных всё в порядке. Но футер не растёт в высоту из-за чего его данные накладываются поверх следующей строки. Как заставить футер подстраиваться под размер содержимого?

На картинке. Вверху строка заголовка группы, которая тоже не растет в высоту при Summary = Group. По центру строка Detail отображается корректно. Внизу строка футера тоже не растёт
[image]